# Ubuntu is crashing after long read/write operation

Tags: dual-boot, grub2, crash, 21.04

I have a dualboot pc (windows 10 primary, ubuntu 21.04 secondary). Windows 10 works fine, but ubuntu crashes when I have long read/write operations. One day I was running a memory check (third party) on ubuntu and it crashes again. Most likely, it's the problem of the operating system itself. How can I fix this? Tech specs are below-

Processor: Intel Core i5-1135G7

GPU: Intel Iris XE Graphics (integrated)

RAM: 16gb ddr4

Hard drive: 1tb SSD (Ubuntu 88gb, Windows rest of the space)

Edit: So now I installed Ubuntu 21.04 on my SSD alongside Windows 10 (11, actually)

Comment: Crashes when running a memory diagnostic usually means bad RAM. Run the official memory test, `memtest`, and go to https://www.memtest86.com/ and download/run their free `memtest` to test your memory. Get at least one complete pass of all the 4/4 tests to confirm good memory. This may take many hours to complete. If it fails/crashes, remove one SODIMM/DIMM and retest. Report back.

Comment: I haven't ran the `memtest` yet, but this my brand-new PC, I don't want dents and missing components on my AIO PC. If you can, please give me another solution @heynnema and actually, now, it just crashes when I start my PC.

Comment: How does it crash now? Does Windows work? I don't know what you mean by *"I don't want dents and missing components on my AIO PC"*. `memtest` is the best solution/suggestion to try and identify the problem with your computer. Start comments to me with @heynnema or I'll miss them.

Comment: Status please...

Comment: Ok, so i ran the `memtest` now, all the tests had passed. Yes, Windows works, but I think its either of these: it could be software corruption, or it could be some malware.

Comment: re: *"actually, now, it just crashes when I start my PC"*... please give more details. Also show me `free -h`.

Comment: This means that when I boot into ubuntu, enter my password, it just crashes when i enter my password and press enter. This doesnt happen on windows.

Comment: also, what is this `free -h`?

Comment: Try this. At the GRUB menu, choose Additional Options, then choose maintenance mode for the newest kernel, and see how far you get. `free -h` tells me something about your memory.